# Unable to unprotect worksheet in Xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I am running xlwings on Windows.  When my code hits the unprotection of the sheet, the code just sits there.  No exceptions, no popups appeared in Excel, just hanging.  I can manually remove protection, the password is fine.

```
 with xw.App() as app:   
        
        wb = app.books.open(local_filename)
        alerts = wb.api.Application.DisplayAlerts  
        wb.api.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        
        ws_data = wb.sheets["Data Input (Do not rename)"]
            
        if wb.api.ProtectStructure:
            wb.api.Unprotect(Password="xxx")
            
        if ws_data.api.ProtectContents:
            ws_data.api.unprotect(Password="xxx")  # hangs here forever
```

Comment: I'm an idiot, it should be Unprotect not unprotect, but no exception was raised, it just hangs....

Comment: That happens...